# How to kill a parallel process(started by subprocess.Popen) and it's subprocess?

Tags: python, subprocess, mitmproxy

I want to use mitmproxy to capture my emulator's flow. My idea is using

`proc = subprocess.Poen('mitmproxy -T -w emulator.log', shell=True)` to start mitmproxy as a parallel process and using `kill pid` to stop mitmproxy.

But `prco.pid` shows thay `prco` is a new shell, mitmproxy is subprocess of `proc`.

`os.killpg(pid, signal.SIGKILL)` can't kill process in diffferent shell;

`os.getpid` get current shell's pid;

`subprocess.Popen(str('kill ',proc.pid), shell=True)` can't kill mitmproxy.

So, how can I kill mitmproxy which was called python script?
Or other method to capture my emulator's flow by mitmproxy.

Comment: usually i passed args like 'killall mitmproxy', but not pythonic way ofcourse

Comment: umh, I need to run lots of emulator and each emulator need one mitmproxy, so it does not suit for me.

Comment: 1- don't use `shell=True`, call `.split()` on the command and call `proc.terminate()` to kill `mitmproxy` process (it works if mitmproxy kills its descendants on SIGTERM) 2- pass `preexec_fn=os.setpgrp` if you want to use `os.killpg(proc.pid, SIGINT)` later (like Ctrl + C in shell) as described in the duplicate question.